# get time difference is not accurate in JS

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a function in `JavaScript` to get the difference between two times:

```
function get_time_difference(laterDate) {
    var earlierDate = new Date();//Now
    var nTotalDiff = laterDate.getTime() - earlierDate.getTime();
    var oDiff = new Object();

    oDiff.days = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    nTotalDiff -= oDiff.days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    oDiff.hours = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    nTotalDiff -= oDiff.hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;

    oDiff.minutes = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000 / 60);
    nTotalDiff -= oDiff.minutes * 1000 * 60;

    oDiff.seconds = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000);

    if (0 == oDiff.minutes && 0 == oDiff.hours) {
        //Do Something
    }
    return oDiff.minutes;
}
```

When times are equal I need to run a particular function,

my problem is that sometimes he returns 59 minutes, while it should return 0 ..

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it this way:

```
function get_time_difference(laterDate) {

var earlierDate = new Date(); //Now
var oDiff = new Object();

oDiff.days = laterDate.getDate() - earlierDate.getDate();
oDiff.hours = laterDate.getHours() - earlierDate.getHours();
oDiff.minutes = laterDate.getMinutes() - earlierDate.getMinutes();
oDiff.seconds = laterDate.getSeconds() - earlierDate.getSeconds();

if (0 == oDiff.minutes && 0 == oDiff.hours) {
//Do Something
}
   return oDiff.minutes;
}
```

Comment: Yes, getMinutes() is the way to go. It might help to change the function to "get_time_difference(laterDate, earlierDate)' so that it can be tested against different patterns.

Answer (score 0):

make it

```
function get_time_difference(laterDate) {

var earlierDate = new Date();//Now
var nTotalDiff = laterDate.getTime() - earlierDate.getTime();
var oDiff = new Object();

oDiff.days = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ));
nTotalDiff -= oDiff.days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

oDiff.hours = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 ));
nTotalDiff -= oDiff.hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;

oDiff.minutes = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / (1000 * 60 ));
nTotalDiff -= oDiff.minutes * 1000 * 60;

oDiff.seconds = Math.floor(nTotalDiff / 1000);

if (0 == oDiff.minutes && 0 == oDiff.hours) {
//Do Something
}
return oDiff.minutes;

}
```

You just need to make sure that what you are dividing with should be evaluated first